# [Ask for some hints]Inserting a sorted array into a constructed BST

Tags: arrays, algorithm, insert, runtime, binary-search-tree

I have a homework question to come up with an efficient algorithm to insert a sorted array with m elements into a(n unbalanced) binary search tree with n elements such that the total run time is O(m+n) instead of m*O(n). As I have struggled for a long time but still do not have a clear direction for the problem, I write this post to ask if possible hints can be given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following algorithm:

1. Perform an inorder traversal of the nodes in the BST, and keep a reference to the previous node that was visited in this traversal. This previous node starts as null. The following invariant is maintained: either the current node has no left child, and then the previous node is either null or an ancestor, or the current node has a left child and the previous node is a descendant.
2. When the next value in the sorted array is smaller than the current node, then insert a new node for this array value as a left child of the current node (when it has no left child) or as a right child of the previous node (when the current node has a left child). Make the newly created node the "previous" node. Increment the index in the array, and repeat this step until the next value in the sorted array is not smaller than the current node.
3. Get the next pair of (previous, current) from the inorder traversal and repeat step 2 until the inorder traversal completes or all array values have been inserted
4. If there are still array values, then append them to the right side of the last node that was found in the inorder traversal, always deepening to the right...

Here is an implementation in JavaScript:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(val) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = null;
    }
    add(val) {
        if (val < this.val) {
            if (!this.left) this.left = new Node(val);
            else this.left.add(val);
        } else {
            if (!this.right) this.right = new Node(val);
            else this.right.add(val);
        }
    }
    * inorder() {  // recursive
        if (this.left) yield * this.left.inorder();
        yield this;
        if (this.right) yield * this.right.inorder();
    }
    addSorted(arr) {
        let i = 0; // index in arr
        let prev = null; // follows behind node
        for (let node of this.inorder()) {
            while (arr[i] < node.val) {
                if (!node.left) prev = node.left = new Node(arr[i++]); 
                else prev = prev.right = new Node(arr[i++]);
                if (i >= arr.length) return;
            }
            prev = node;
        }
        while (i < arr.length) {
            prev = prev.right = new Node(arr[i++]);
        }
    }
}

// Demo
// Initialise tree and print the inorder traversal
let root = new Node(40);
for (let i of [30, 70, 20, 35, 60, 80, 5, 55]) root.add(i);
for (let node of root.inorder()) console.log(node.val);

// Apply the algorithm for adding a sorted list of values
root.addSorted([1, 2, 8, 22, 38, 39, 43, 50, 51, 59, 72, 100]);
console.log("after having added sorted array:");
for (let node of root.inorder()) console.log(node.val);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I do get the idea of this algorithm but I concern if the run time is O(n+m) since you call in-order walk each time when you insert a new element?

Comment: The inorder walk *continues* from where it was. I used an iterator. So in total there is only one complete tree traversal